# Loop and process multiple HDFS files in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have multiple files in my HDFS folder and I want to loop and run my scala transformation logic on it.

I am using below script which is working fine in my development environment using local files but it is failing when I run on my HDFS environment. Any idea where am I doing wrong please?

```
val files = new File("hdfs://172.X.X.X:8020/landing/").listFiles.map(_.getName).toList

files.foreach { file =>
print(file) 
val event = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("hdfs://172.X.X.X:8020/landing/" + file)
event.show(false)
}
```

Can someone correct it or suggest alternative solution please.

Comment: what is the error that you got ?

Comment: I will share the error message once I connect to the server but I remember the error message as "java.lang.nullpointerexception"

Comment: ok let's see the error and we will discuss ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mohana. It's working.

Comment: @Nassereddine, below was the error message with my earlier code

 java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Hadoop IO library to handle hadoop files.

code:

```
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark=SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

val fs=FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://172.X.X.X:8020/"),spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

fs.globStatus(new Path("/landing/*")).toList.foreach{
   f=>
   val event = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("hdfs://172.X.X.X:8020/landing/" + f.getPath.getName)
   event.show(false)
}
```